# Como fazer uma Grid com quadrados?

Tags: java, swing

Gostaria de fazer algo como esse aqui, uma Grid baseado em uma matriz(e que baseado no valor da matriz, defina uma cor a célula correspondente), e que eu possa manipular ela com o mouse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fazer com que? Acho que a pergunta está ampla demais.

Comment: Vou dar uma melhora, mas caso esteja perguntando a linguagem, é Java(está nas tags).

Comment: Que é java eu vi, mas da pra fazer isso até em modo de texto. Você não definiu um ponto de partida. Existem N apis em java pra tentar fazer isso.

Comment: Qualquer uma eu aceito, eu apenas preciso fazer isso, a que você acha que se encaixa melhor pode colocar como resposta.

Comment: Só feche um pouco o escopo a alguma API grafica de java, como swing, para poder ser possivel responder sem que ela seja fechada. Se eu adicionar essa tag, pode ser considerado alteração da intenção pela moderação.

Answer (score 4):

Baseado num exemplo de [tabuleiro de xadrez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11602223/5524514), fiz esse exemplo de *grid* preenchido com JLabels, onde ao clicar em algum deles, altera a cor de fundo para preto. Usando ele como uma base, você pode desenvolver melhor a sua ideia.

Esta classe criará um painel de JLabels populados num *GridLayout*:

```
class GridPane extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int rows;
    private int column;

    private JLabel[][] squares;

    public GridPane(int rows, int column) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.column = column;
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, column));
        this.squares = new JLabel[this.rows][this.column];

        for (int r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.column; c++) {
                SquareLabel square = new SquareLabel();
                this.squares[r][c] = square;
                this.add(square);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Criei também uma classe, a parte chamada `SquareLabel` pro caso de você querer personalizar algo em cada quadrado:

```
class SquareLabel extends JLabel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SquareLabel() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        addMouseListener(new ClickChangeColor());
    }
}
```

Separei também o *listener*, apesar de que para o exemplo nem seria necessário, mas com ele já criado, facilita adição de outras ações que podem estar relacionadas ao mouse:

```
class ClickChangeColor extends MouseAdapter {

    boolean clicked = false;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        clicked = !clicked;
        JLabel square = (JLabel) e.getSource();
        Color color = clicked ? Color.black : square.getParent().getBackground();
        square.setBackground(color);
    }
}
```

Em execução:

[image: GIF Executável]

Fiz exemplo executável que pode ser testado no [Github](https://github.com/diegofelipem/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/swing/examples5/ChessBoardTest.java).