# Adicionando componentes a um JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Olá, estou tentando construir uma interface simples para implementar um campo minado. O resultado final deveria ser algo como uma grade de botoes, bem simples.O problema que estou tendo é que quando eu crio uma instancia desa clase, apenas um botão aparece como na imagem a seguir:[image: resultado da execução]. segue o código que estou escrevendo.

```
package ms;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FrameBasico extends JFrame {
    JPanel painelMinas = new JPanel();
    int x = 9; int y = 9;
    MyJToggleButton[][] botoes = new MyJToggleButton[x][y];
    FrameBasico(){        
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        painelMinas.setSize(this.getSize());        
        painelMinas.setBackground(Color.red);                
        colocarBotoes();        
        this.add(painelMinas);                        
    }

    public void colocarBotoes(){        
        for(int ipslon = 0; ipslon < y; ipslon++){
            for(int xis = 0; xis < x; xis++){
                botoes[xis][ipslon] =  new MyJToggleButton();                                                                               
                painelMinas.add(botoes[xis][ipslon]);                                
                botoes[xis][ipslon].setVisible(true);                      
            }
        }        
        this.setVisible(true);        
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
       FrameBasico f = new FrameBasico();
    }
}
```

Comment: Julian, seu código não é executavel, por favor, forneça um codigo que seja **[mcve]** para que possamos testar o problema.

Comment: Imagino que seu problema seja fazer que nem eu fiz [**neste link**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238086/como-fazer-uma-grid-com-quadrados), se for, confirme nos comentarios.

Comment: Se bem é parecido, no codigo do link é usado o gridLayout. Eu queria tentar me abstrair do uso dos layouts, por isso tentei posicionar os botões com o metodo setLocation()...
Quanto ao exemplo minimo, voce se referia a ter uma clase main?

Comment: Você não deve usar valores absolutos, os layouts existem justamente para facilitar esse tipo de problema que voce está tendo. Recomendo que veja a outra pergunta, de uma olhada no layout la sugerido, ele atende e faz o que voce pretende.

Comment: realmente, vendo a outra pergunta percebo que aquela solução é melhor.
Vocẽ pode me recomendar al tuturial sobre layouts ? ainda acho bem complicado entender como funcionam e como usa-los

Comment: Tem a documentação deles: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html